# Git: file on remote server is not being overwritten with updated version on merge

Tags: git, github, merge

I must have accidentally pushed up a file where I did not remove the merge error markers (`<<<<HEAD`) and it broke my site.

I checked out the problem file, found the merge conflict and fixed the code. I then went to commit the file but get the message `nothing to commit (working directory clean)`.

Regardless, I pushed the changes up to GitHub. In GitHub I can view the file and see that the code is correct. Great!

I then went to merge the fixed code into my remote site. But nothing happens. The merge performs fine, no errors, but the site still remained broken.

Curious, I checked out the same file. The bad code is still there, on the remote repo.

Would anyone know what's happening and how I could fix it? Here's the steps I took:

1. `git checkout develop file.etc`
2. fix code
3. `git status` to confirm file is modified
4. `git add .`, `git commit` and `git push` to Github
5. Check on GitHub to see that file is modifed
6. `git merge branch-name`
7. Test to see if site is working

Comment: Did you do `git status` _after_ adding the file to the stage?  You could have been looking at a cached version of your site.  Use `git add path/to/file` explicity.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I just tried that then. After I ran `git commit` then do `git status` it says there's nothing to commit. (Yeah, I've cleared the cache on the site too)

Comment: No, that's not what I asked.  I asked if you ran `git status` after _adding_ the file, not committing the file.

Comment: To be blunt here: I think you may not have added your changed file to the stage at all.  Hence, it never made it to the server.

Comment: I think in a way you're right. Experimenting, I found that immediately after I checkout the file I run `git status` I see that it is staged and modified. I then make the changes to the code and `git status` and see that I have the 2 'versions' of the file: 1 staged and 1 unstaged. I then `git add .` and run `git status` again, but now have no files - either staged or unstaged. It's like updating the file in stage cancels it out, for lack of a better word.

Comment: You're doing something wrongly with how you add your files.

Comment: Honestly, I don't know what I could be doing differently. I've only tried `git add .` and `git add path/filename.ext`. Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: Remove the markers, `git add path/to/file.php`, `git status` and verify that it's staged, `git commit -m 'fixed the bug'`, `git push origin yourBranch`, that's it

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing, but this process fails at the 
"verify it's staged" point. There's nothing to commit.

Comment: After you have edited the file, did `git status` show that file as being dirty?

Comment: Yep it did - modified and unstaged

Answer (score 1):

OK, I think I understand what may have been going on here.

The remote repo is it's self a branch. I merged the bad file into that remote branch, but was 'checking it out' and trying to fix it on my original branch.

Since the file was fixed on my original branch, as visible up on GitHub, staging it wouldn't work - git didn't see any difference between the file I just fixed and the one already part of the branch, that's why it 'disappeared' when I added it and said there was nothing to commit.

As for why I couldn't merge in my branch in with the remote branch a 2nd time, I'm not sure.